# SPSS String Column Split into 2

Tags: spss

I have a column with names and middles names separated by space. Is there a command that will let me put everything after space into a new column? (ie first names and middle names each in their own columns)

I am using SPSS.

Thanks!

Comment: If you found one of your answers helpful, please consider selecting it as the accepted answer. That will assign credit to the folks who have helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the variable to split is called `Name`, try:

```
string first middle (a50).
compute #x = char.index(Name, " ") > 0.
do if #x = 1.
   compute first = char.substr(Name, 1, char.index(Name, " ")).
   compute middle = char.substr(Name, char.index(Name, " ")).
else.
   compute first = Name.
end if.
exe.
```

Comment: +1, instead of computing `char.index(Name, " ") > 0` multiple times, I would suggest putting it in a scratch variable before the do if statement. That way you only have to compute it once, instead of 3 times. Also you can omit `char.length(Name)` for the middle computation. Default behavior is to return to the end of the string if omitted.